# Does this matrix operation have a name?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, stochastic-processes

I'm working with a particular operation on square matrixes of size $2n\times 2n$. I'm wondering if it has a name and whether its properties have been studied before. It arises in the context of the statistical mechanics of small classical systems and is applied in this case to stochastic matrices, where it can be thought of as a kind of time reversal.

The operation first divides the matrix up into $n\times n$ blocks, each of size $2\times 2$. It then does a "block transpose" on these blocks, and then it swaps the two diagonal elements of each block.

In other words, a matrix with elements $a_{ij}$ maps to the matrix with elements $a_{j+2(j\%2)-1, \,i+2(i\%2)-1}$, with $\%$ being the modulo operator. For example, writing the operation as a prime,

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} \\
 a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} \\
 a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} \\
 a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & a_{44} \\
\end{pmatrix}'
=
\begin{pmatrix}
 a_{22} & a_{12} & a_{42} & a_{32} \\
 a_{21} & a_{11} & a_{41} & a_{31} \\
 a_{24} & a_{14} & a_{44} & a_{34} \\
 a_{23} & a_{13} & a_{43} & a_{33} \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Note that this operation is self-inverse, and that applying it to a stochastic matrix gives another stochastic matrix as a result.

I'm also interested in whether there is a name for the class of matrices $A$ such that $A'=A$.

Comment: Call your transform $f(M)$.  Note that $f(M) + f(N) = f(M+N)$ and that $f(cM) = cf(M)$.  Thus your transform is a matrix itself. A $(2n)^2$ by $(2n)^2$ matrix.

Comment: The transformation is a composition of a few linear involutions, and is involution itself ($A$ is involution if $A^2$ is the identity map).

Comment: "Block transpose" part is equivalent to non-hermitian-transpose of a complex matrix represented by 2x2 real blocks. But for those the diagonal elements are always the same ( the real part a is represented by a times 2x2 identity ).